# Why a generic like Node<Item> instead of a regular Node

Tags: java, algorithm, generics

I'm taking Algorithms I on coursera and came across the implementation of a Data Structure called Bag.

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Bag.java.html

However I don't undertand why the use a Node class like this:

```
private static class Node<Item> {
        private Item item;
        private Node<Item> next;
    }
```

Why is the Item in there? Why can't I use:

```
private class Node {

        private Item item;
        private Node next;
}
```

Is there a difference? Thanks

Comment: What does `Item` mean in the context of a non-generic world to you?  I don't see anywhere that it could be introduced, or what it truly represents.  What you've got there is a `Node` that holds `Item`s, whereas the generic is a `Node` that can hold literally *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference.

`Node<Item>` uses what's called a generic. `Item` in not a class, it's simply an identifier of any element.

Read the Java source code, you would see something like `Node<E>`... Same thing. Name is not important.

For the other one, you need an `Item` class to be defined and that is the only datatype a Node can hold